# Winform RichTextBox get last character entered using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am using the following code to extract the last character( the character just typed) using the following code

```
 private string GetTypedChar()
    {
        string currentChar = "";
        int i = rtfText.SelectionStart; 
        if (i > 0)
        {
            currentChar = rtfText.Text.Substring(i-1, 1);
            MessageBox.Show(i+":"+currentChar);
        }
        return currentChar;
    }
```

But this is giving me wrong results. If the word entered is "RS" the after pressing R the message box shows 1: (blank) then on typing S message box  shows 2:R
How to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like the event you are using is firing before the input is processed instead of after.

Comment: KeyDown event of RichTextBox

Comment: Then isn't e.KeyCode the last char (before its written - which is why you don't see it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important question is **when** you execute that code. Sounds like you subscribe to the 'KeyDown' event. By the time this event is raised, the key stroke has not yet been processed by the form --> So you don't see the change. You could use the `KeyUp` event. When this gets fired, your control has a changed context.

This will, however, not help you, if the new character is not the last one. The user could change the courser position and type a character. Then the new character is somewhere in the middle of the text. This can be solved by actually checking *which* key has been pressed. This information is in the `KeyEventArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

to get the last entered character. You can handle the keyup event

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        char last = (char)e.KeyValue;
    }
```

you can get the last character of your rich text box

```
string lastCharacter = rtfText.Text.SubString(rtfText.Text.Length - 1,1);
```

or

```
char last = rtfText.Text[rtfText.Text.Length - 1];
```

or

Comment: `SelectionStart` ensures its the last character from the insertion point, not the last character of the document

Answer (score 1):

You could just eliminate `GetTypedChar()` altogether and subscribe to the `KeyPress` event.

Note that this won't give you the position of the character though, if you need that information.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Last char typed: {0}", e.KeyChar));
}
```